# Document.writeln in a New frame not window.open

Tags: javascript, html

How can I write new lines on a frame in the same window? For now I have it creating a new Window with window.open. But now I need it in a frame.

I have an html with the two frames(form and result) and I need to write in the second by pressing a button on the first frame.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> Create Curriculum</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <frameset rows="50%,50%">
        <frame id="form" src="from.html"/>
        <frame id="curri" src=""/>
    </frameset>
```

You intercat with the form adding info to the inputs and saving the information. There's also a button that generates the curriculum using the info entered below.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function genCurriculum() {
    //I want to capture the second frame with id "curri"
    var curri = parent.document.getElementById("curri");
    curri.document.writeln("<h2>Head of the curriculum...</h2>");
    //The others writeln for creating the curriculum
}
```

I want to know how to write in the frame, not in a new window.

And NOT using `Jquery`, just pure `JavaScript`. (Teacher requirement)

Answer (score 0):

Is this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jameslafferty/G8Hw3/) what you want to have happen?

Html:

```
<form>
    <input name="nextLine" type="text" />
    <button type="button">
        <span>Add a line</span>
    </button>
</form>
<iframe height="100" width="200"></iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var button, iframe, input;
    function addLine (cD, input, val) {
        return function () {
            var body, line;
            body = cD.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
            line = cD.createElement('p');
            line.innerText = val.toString() + ': ' + input.value;
            body.appendChild(line);
            val += 1;
        }
    }
    button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
    iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    button.addEventListener('click', addLine(iframe.contentDocument, input, 0), true);
}());
```

Comment: Not this, sorry I've explained bad myself. I'm going to edit my first post for better explanation. And sorry for my english.

Comment: It might be helpful to post a fiddle with your existing code (to clarify what you're looking for).